# May the word "evict" refer to apartment, or only to a person?

Tags: grammaticality, terminology

Can only a person be evicted, or can the word be used to refer to person's rented unit or apartment, as in "evict your unit"?

Comment: Only a person can be evicted. If you evicted the unit, that would have a serious impact on the structural integrity of your building.

Comment: I find it intriguing that someone has closevoted as "opinion-based". My opinion is that anyone who refers to *evicting an apartment block* is almost certainly confusing ***evict*** with ***evacuate***. But this is General Reference, and can easily be answered using any dictionary.

Comment: So if I evict everyone from the whole block, I think I could say that "the whole block was evicted" in a metonymous kind of way.

Answer (score 1):

You can say that a person is evicted, not a building or a place:

***To evict*** (usage):

> - [Evict](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/evict) somebody (from something) to force somebody to leave a house or land, especially when you have the legal right to do so
>
>   - *A number of tenants have been evicted for not paying the rent*.
>   - *The council has tried to get them evicted*
>   - *Police had to evict demonstrators from the building*.

(OLD)